# NullPointerExceptions while executing LoadTest on WSO2BPS

Tags: mysql, nullpointerexception, apache-axis, wso2, wso2-business-process

While performing loadtests on WSO2 BPS 3.2.0 we`ve ran onto the problem.

Let me tell you more about out project and our actions.
Our BPS process is designed to manage some interactions with 3 systems. Basically it is "spread" on two parts - first one to CREATE INSTANCE in one of systems, then waiting a bit, and then SELECT OFFER in instance context. 
In real life it looks like: user wants to get a product, the application asks system for an offers and then the user selects offer from available ones.
IN BPS the first part is a straight-forward process, the second part is spread on two flows - one to refresh information with a new offers, and another is to wait if the user chooses one of them.
Our aim is to stand about 1000-1500 simulatious threads on the load-test. An external systems are simulated by mockups executed by LoadUI.

We can achieve our goal if we disable "Process-Level Monitoring Events" in deployment descriptor (set it to "none") of our process. Everything goes well and smooth for hours.

But if we enable this feature (and we need to), everything falls with an error very soon (on about 100-200 run):

[2015-07-28 17:47:02,573] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELProcessProxy} -  Error processing response for MEX null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELProcessProxy.onResponse(BPELProcessProxy.java:402)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELProcessProxy.onAxisServiceInvoke(BPELProcessProxy.java:187)
        at 
[....Et cetera....]

After the first appearance of this error another one type appears - other threads just fall after the timeout.

It seems that database is ok (by the way, it is MySQL 5.6.25). The dashboard shows no extreme levels of input or output.

So I think the BPS itself makes a bottleneck. We have gave it 8gb heap and its conf options are set for extreme amounts of threads (if it possible negative values are set and if not - just ridiculously big like 100000).

Anyone has ever faced this problem? Appreciate any help very much.

Comment: It appears that not the BPS, but the database is a bottleneck. Something is wrong with concurrent threads.

Comment: Seems like BPS 3.5.0 version solves this problem, but not sure yet about high-load scenarios. But I already know for sure one scenario that causes NullPointerException on 3.2.0 and works fine on 3.5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in BPS 3.5.0 version, refer to release-notes